# MVC Passing Data as Hidden (Not in URL, not as Hidden HTML)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm using MVC 3 C#.NET.

Is there any way to pass values between pages (two different page with different controllers) without exposing the value in the URL or as hidden values? Is the last resort using a Session variable? Or would you recommend encoding the hidden field (ala ViewState style) and parse that to the controller?

I'm passing several values that I want hidden from the user as they might try to play with the values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: better to rely on server side mechanism i.e `Session Variables` , since any client side solution shall always be vulnerable to play with.

Comment: Why do you not want to use url parameters or hidden values?

Comment: If you post more about nature of hidden data and why exactly you need that data to be hidden, maybe you could get better answers. I mean, Generally, you should not need that. If possible, it's better to let users change input and always validate, than to encrypt and hide data and skip validation

Comment: There are no sensitive data, more on 'plumbing' data where some hard-coded values that the controller needs are saved on the form and passed. I don't want to reveal too much in the HTML form about how the web app works, so I figured that I should obscure the plumbing data a little bit.

Comment: @Furqan I don't want to rely on Session variables as they operate on one object at a time and will cause problems on multiple instances of the web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still used hidden fields, but encoded it to Base64, ala ViewState style. It obscures the real values for most users.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a POST and hidden fields in your form. POST fields do not show up in your URL only GET's. Always try to minimize the use of session variables, those should be used to store user login information, user settings, preferences, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simply persist this data in some backing storage on your server (could be a database or whatever backing storage you are using). I am not fan of a Session myself so I don't recommend it using it at all. If the user is not supposed to see or modify this data, then this data should not even be passed to the view. It should stay where it belongs => on the server.

Comment: Actually, this is not sensitive data. I have a controller that has a 'mode' depending on a value passed. I don't want my users mucking up with the hidden data, although you are certainly right that some data doesn't need to reach the view.